# MySQL Stored Procedure - Transaction rollback not working

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, rollback

I have migrated my database from a MySQL web server to a MariaDB local server, everything is the same, however my transactions in stored procedures aren't rolling back. Here is one of my stored procedures:

```
newstockitem:
BEGIN    
    DECLARE LID INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE GID INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE avXR DECIMAL(12,6) DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE `rollback` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `rollback` = 1;

    SELECT COUNT(ID) INTO @cnt FROM Cats WHERE Parent=SCID;

    IF @cnt > 0 THEN
        SELECT '~hasParent';
        LEAVE newstockitem;
    END IF;   


    SELECT b.XR INTO avXR 
    FROM Suppliers a 
    LEFT JOIN Currencies b
        ON b.ID = a.Currency
    WHERE a.ID=SupID;   

    START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT MAX(GroupID)+1 INTO @newGrpID FROM StockItems;
    INSERT INTO StockItems (Item,
                               SubCatID,
                               Qty,
                               lastAudit,
                               AvgXR,
                               SupplierID,
                               PackPrice,
                               GroupID,
                               QtyInPack,
                               Ref,
                               Size,
                               Def,
                               PorpDef)
    VALUES(Itm,
    SCID,
    Qnty,
    Qnty,
    avXR,
    SupID,
    PPrice,
    @newGrpID,
    QtyPack,
    Rf,
    IF(Sze>0,Sze,NULL),
    1,
    2);            

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO LID;
    SELECT GroupID
    INTO GID
    FROM StockItems
    WHERE ID = LID;


    INSERT INTO Logs (UserID, TypeID, RelID, Datetime) VALUES(Usr, 17, LID, NOW());

        **SELECT 'leave';
        LEAVE newstockitem;**

    IF Qnty <> 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO Logs (ParentID, UserID, TypeID, RelID, QtyAdj, Datetime) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), Usr, 20, LID, Qnty, NOW());
    END IF;

    IF `rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        SELECT '~rb';
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
        SELECT CONCAT('~succ-', GID);
    END IF;
END
```

After the 2 INSERTS, I've put a temporary LEAVE. When this leave gets hit, the INSERTS exist in the database as if it's been committed. All my tables are InnoDB, and my user has full privileges. Anybody know what may be causing this?

Comment: Leaving stored procedure using a `LEAVE` does not `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` the transaction, it's still active, see the following [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a20a9983a543a7e2b697c15801fc943e).

Comment: Use `FOR UPDATE` on any `SELECTs` that fetch rows you might change in the same transaction.